# Populating a ComboBox with a Dynamic Range in a single column

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am creating a Userform in excel and in it I have a search box which searches All the values in Column A. When selecting the value in the search box. I want to pull through all the possible values relating to the value in column A. For example.... In the Combobox that is to pull through the Project Number. When the person selects LR UK 1 I would like the Project Number combo box to pull through a selection of either 1 or 2....

The thing is my code is pulling through just the value of 2. I can understand why my code pulls through what it does however I am struggling to to get it to pull through all of the values in the corresponding column to the project name range.

[image: Sample Below]

```
Private Sub Find_Click()

Dim searchRange As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim mysearch As String
    
mysearch = CBProjName.Value

With Sheets("Records")
    Set searchRange = Sheets("Records").Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    TBCaseNumber = foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    CBProjNumbers.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 2).Value 'this is the val that only displays 2
            
Else
     MsgBox "Uh oh, things have gone a little sideways and the project " & CBProjName.Value & " cannot be located. Please try another Project!"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is loop through the data and grab all the project numbers for the selected project.

To speed things up when doing that we can put all the data in an array and loop through that.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Find_Click()
Dim arrData As Variant
Dim arrProjectNos As Variant
Dim mysearch As String
Dim cnt As Long
Dim idx As Long
    
    If CBProjName.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        mysearch = CBProjName.Value
    
        With Sheets("Records")
            Set searchRange = Sheets("Records").Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        End With
    
        arrData = searchRange.Resize(, 3).Value
    
        ReDim arrProjectNos(1 To UBound(arrData, 1))
        
        For idx = LBound(arrData, 1) To UBound(arrData, 1)
            If arrData(idx, 1) = mysearch Then
                TBCaseNumber = arrData(idx, 2)
                cnt = cnt + 1
                arrProjectNos(cnt) = arrData(idx, 3)
            End If
        Next idx
        
        If cnt > 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve arrProjectNos(1 To cnt)
            CBProjNumbers.List = arrProjectNos
        Else
            MsgBox "Uh oh, things have gone a little sideways and the project " & mysearch & " cannot be located. Please try another Project!"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select a project to search for!"
    End If
    
End Sub
```